# CORS allowing jsonplaceholder

Tags: django, vue.js, cors

I'm learning vue and I'm experimenting with API calls with axios to my local django server.
Therefore I encountered CORS errors.
I already know how CORS works and why it is blocking my calls, however when I try to send a call to [this fake API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for testing, it works flawlessly.
How is cors allowing it?

Here's an example code:

```
axios.get('https://localhost:8000/api/posts')
.then( () => console.log('Local server working :)'))

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
.then( () => console.log('Fake api working :)'))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The server answers with CORS related headers.

[image]